# Function render after splice and setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, splice

I want my React function to re-render after I splice an array.

Here Is (part of) the function (using Hooks):

```
function showProblem() {
  const [andArray, setAndArray] = useState([]);

const deleteTag = (i, arr) => {
    let and = andArray;
    switch (arr) {
      case "and":
        and.splice(i, 1);
        setAndArray(and);
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };


return(
<div>
    {andArray.map((and, i) => {
            return (
              <span
                onClick={() => deleteTag(i, "and")}
                key={i}
              >
                {and}
              </span>
            );
     })}
</div>
)
}
```

When I click on the SPAN element, I want my "andArray.map" to render again.

The splice is working correctly, my array is ok... but the function does not re-render.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.splice` mutates the array. React states have to be immutable. The immuatble way would be:

```
  setAndState(and.filter((_, i2) => i2 !== i));
```

Comment: It works... can you please explain me that "i2" you're comparing? Thanks a lot anyway!... 

understood, It's just the name you gave to the index variable.

Thanks :)

Comment: he needs to exclude the item of the array at the specific index `i`, so when `i2 === i`, the element should be excluded, that's why he filters the array with the condition `i2 !== i`

Answer (score 0):

React state has to receive a change but as the array address stays the same nothing is re-rendered. **In short: React State doesn't check *deep*.**

I just created a new array from the old one. This way an address change is triggered. It is readable and it makes you be able to use functions of splice like inserting.

```
  and.splice(1, 0, newValueAtIndexOne);
  setAndState(Array.from(and));
```